# BGS/LQM Groundhog - drawing tools for cross section

Tags: gis

I am using the new BGS Groundhog Desktop

I have created a cross section but cant access the drawing tools.  I have tried hovering over where I think the tools should be but nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks - that works

Answer (score 0):

You need to select which layer you want to draw into. For example, there is a layer in the cross-section that is always there called "Geology" which you can draw geology line-work into. Single-click on that layer to make it active (it will turn orange), and the drawing tools should appear in the form of a sort of floating tool palette control. Click on the drawing tool you wish to use and start drawing. When you are done, click on the tool again to drop it, or click on the "Geology" layer again to de-activate it.